# How to create udev rule in Ubuntu for chrome app USB access?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, usb, udev

I'm trying to access a USB device through a chrome app, but it's not working.  Then I noticed I need to set a `udev` rule, but the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb#caveats) are confusing.  I'm supposed to make a file called `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-yourdevicename.rules` but what is the device name?  The results of `lsusb` for the device are:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0403:6015 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd Bridge(I2C/SPI/UART/FIFO)
```

Which part of that is the `yourdevicename`????  I have no idea.

The next step is to put this in the udev file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="[yourdevicevendor]", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"
```

but to check, is idVendor 0403 and yourdevicevendor 6015 ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after much [weeping and gnashing of teeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weeping_and_gnashing_of_teeth), I figured it out.  The 'yourdevicename' can be anything at all.  The `ATTR{idVendor}=="[yourdevicevendor]"` should be `ATTR{idVendor}=="6015"`.  Anyway, I ended up following the example at the bottom of the page [here](http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/), which has this format:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", ATTR{idProduct}=="6015", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

So the vendor id is 0403 and product id is 6015 (both in hex).

Surprising that in the year of our lord 2017 something as simple as connecting a USB to a browser can be so incredibly painful and difficult.